# Cannot change a variable value

Tags: java

So, I'm making a simple program that is using 2 classes.

The first class contains this:

```
public class A{
    private int x;

    public A(){
        x = changexvalue(x);
        System.out.println(x); //Check value
    }

    private int changexvalue(int x){
        x = x + 2;
        return x;
    }

    public int getxvalue(){
        return x;
    }
}
```

The second class contains this:

```
public class B{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.getxvalue());
    }
}
```

So, the problem is this. The first output(in class A) prints 2 but the class B output shows 0(I want the class B output show 2). How is this possible and how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360663/variable-can-not-be-changed?rq=1

Comment: `x = changexvalue(x);` where in your method you are doing `x = x + 2;` is confusing. Do you think that you are passing variable `x` or value of `x` to `changexvalue` method? Do you know that Java is always [pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)?

Comment: How can you access `a` in `B.main` when it's not `static`? Did you simplify your code and deleted too much?

Comment: How it's possible that you use a(non static variable) from static main function?

Comment: I tried the code, everything works good : 2 2

Comment: I tired the code too, everything works good too: 2 2

Comment: It's still not working with me should I make the x static?

Comment: you should make a static. Also Java is case sensitive, there no Public keyword in it. How it even compiles for you?

Comment: @user3680043 The code you are showing does not produce the output you describe. Please show your actual code. For instance, your class `A` won't compile, given that you've capitalized `Public`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.x` to refer to the class' member variable `x`. `x` on its own refers to the local variable.

Comment: Which local variable are you talking about. There no local variable x in A constructor.

Comment: To elaborate: in `changexvalue`, the `x` that is being changed/returned (and thus printed when `a` is created) is the local `x` (the parameter), NOT the instance variable `x`.  An alternate fix would be to use a different name for the local variable.

Comment: this.x on the getxvalue() method or the changexvalue method?

Comment: @user3680043: Use a different name than just `x`. `y` would suffice.

Comment: @user3680043: `this.x` would mean the same thing (the member variable) in both, but its only in `changexvalue` that `x` does not mean the same thing as `this.x`.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The method returns the value of the local `x`, _which is then assigned to the instance variable `x` by the constructor._

Answer (score 0):

`x` got [shadowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) here. You use two variablees with the same name so only the inner variable (the input of the method at this point) is accessable and `x` the attribute of your class can not be accessed.

```
private int changexvalue(int x){
    x = x + 2;
    return x;
}
```

replace it with

```
private int changexvalue(int y){
    x = y + 2;
    return x;
}
```

or use `this` to make clear where you use the `x` Attribute of the class and where you use the `x` input variable of your method:

```
private int changexvalue(int x){
    this.x = x + 2;
    return this.x;
}
```

Comment: or just `return y + 2;`.

Comment: And calling member functions from constructors is bad practice anyway.

Comment: this no the cause, even if x is shadowed in changexvalue it's should be overwritten in A(),because there no local x variable.

Comment: @Bathsheba why bad practice?

Comment: Someone might override the function in a child class. Then all hell will break loose. In C++ the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @PeterRader: because you can override the method by an extending class and thereby changing the behavior of the constructor without knowing of the changed behavior.

Comment: @PeterRader methods are polymorphic so if you override it in derived class constructor of super class will invoked overridden method, which may cause many problems. You are safe only in case of private/final/static methods which are not polymorphic.

Comment: Not bad prictise if it's final and private

Comment: It doesn't matter. The method returns the value of the local x, _which is then assigned to the instance variable x by the constructor_.